# O que significa ns3 e ns4 em um arquivo XML?

Tags: xml

```
<ns3:dadoTransporteTransportXml>
  <uuidDadoSerializado>5444429-da1cb4c9-ea75-4149-bb10-def6a6173731</uuidDadoSerializado>
  <tipoDadoSerializado>4</tipoDadoSerializado>
  <codIbge>4205407</codIbge>
  <cnesDadoSerializado>5444429</cnesDadoSerializado>
  <numLote>2</numLote>
    <ns4:fichaAtendimentoIndividualMasterTransport>
      <headerTransport>
        <lotacaoForm>
          <profissionalCNS>137048659790001</profissionalCNS>
```

Essa é a parte de um arquivo xml que peguei na internet para estudo. Terei que criar um arquivo semelhante a esse para importar em outro sistema. Eu entendi as tags com informações dentro semelhante a html, mas não sei o significado de `ns3` e `ns4` nesse código. O que quer dizer?

É necessário usar o `ns` pro xml funcionar?

Vocês podem ver o arquivo completo => [AQUI](http://dab.saude.gov.br/portaldab/esus/manualExportacaoV20/ExemplosXML/CadastroIndividual.esus.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

é Apenas um `Namespace`, que no caso do seu arquivo de exemplo, foi colocado apenas `nsX` acredito que inadequadamente.

Veja a documentação: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Comment: porque inadequadamente? quer dizer que não há necessidade de usá-lo?

Comment: Usar ou não, não é a questão, quis dizer inadequado os termos, ns1, ns2, ns3, .... Rs

Comment: Como é um arquivo exemplo, a numeração deve ser pra facilitar o entendimento. Então no caso,eu posso retirá-lo? veja ele completo aqui https://goo.gl/XPVMyC

Comment: Pensei que fosse algum arquivo "real" que você estava usando como exemplo. Tirar ou não, não sei te falar se pode